# Como funciona o coletor de lixo do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memória, garbage-collector

## Variáveis simples

Me corrijam se eu estiver errado, mas no Java o coletor de lixo elimina objetos que não são mais referenciados:

```java
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
cliente = null; // o coletor de lixo cuidará disso
```

O mesmo vale para o JavaScript?

```js
var obj = {foo: "bar"};
obj = null; // isso foi limpo da memória?
```

## Funções

Qual a condição para variáveis dentro de funções serem eliminadas? Sei que há pelos menos algumas condições em que elas precisam ser mantidas:

```js
var foo = (function() {
    var text = "bar";
    var bar = function() {
        alert(text);
    };

    return bar;
})();
```

No caso acima a variável `text` precisa ser mantida (creio eu), pois ela ainda está sendo referenciada pela função retornada.

## DOM

Conteúdo removido é eliminado da memória?

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.innerHTML = ""; // isso será limpo?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Parece que você já entendeu bem como funciona, mas vou comentar cada caso.

## Variáveis simples

Se não houver mais nenhuma referência *ao objeto*, ele pode ser eliminado:

```
var obj = {foo: "bar"};
obj = null; // sim, isso foi limpo da memória
```

Porém:

```
var bar = {foo: "bar"};
var boo = bar;
bar = null; // bar não contém mais nada, mas o objeto ainda está em boo
```

Ou seja, no caso de múltiplas referências ao mesmo objeto, todas precisam ser nulificadas para que ele seja marcado como lixo. Aliás, importante: a memória não é liberada no exato momento em que a referência é setada para `null`. Nesse momento, o valor se torna "coletável", mas o GC roda no momento em que a implementação achar mais oportuno.

## Funções

Você tem razão, se um valor for capturado em uma *closure*, ele não pode ser liberado:

```
var foo = (function() {
    var text = "bar";
    var bar = function() {
        alert(text);
    };

    return bar;
})();
```

Ou seja, a string "bar" continuará existindo enquanto `foo` existir.

## DOM

Hoje em dia não existe muita diferença ao se lidar com objetos do DOM e objetos comuns, As regras explicadas acima se aplicam da mesma maneira. Mas antigamente não era o caso. Eu me lembro de excluir elementos do DOM sem excluir seus *event listeners*, e mais tarde ao inserir outro nó com o mesmo ID do que tinha sido removido, o listener ressuscitava! Isso se não me engano ocorria não só no IE, mas também no Firefox. Mas tudo indica que esse tipo de coisa seja mesmo problema do passado (como o clássico [problema das referências circulares no IE](http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html), que exigia uma série de [malabarismos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff728624.aspx) para ser evitado, até o IE8).

## Reference Counting vs. Mark and Sweep

[Segundo a MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management), o GC de todos os browsers modernos usam um algoritmo do tipo *Mark and Sweep* em vez de *Reference Counting*. No Mark and Sweep, o coletor percorre todos os objetos vivos a partir de uma raiz (o objeto global, no caso), e considera "vivo" qualquer objeto que possa ser referenciado nessa busca. Na prática, isso significa que a memória pode ser liberada mesmo que ainda exista alguma referência ao objeto a ser limpo, mas essa referência não tenha mais como ser acessada e utilizada pelo programa. Isso resolveu o problema das referências circulares mencionado acima.

Comment: Refiz a parte do DOM a partir de referências, e incluí uma seção sobre os tipos de GC.

Comment: Por que as referências precisam ser nulificadas para serem marcadas como lixo?

Comment: @FREEZE Porque enquanto houver alguma referência apontando para determinado objeto o coletor de lixo considera que esse objeto está em uso, e portanto não pode ser removido da memória.

Comment: Mas não pode ser qualquer valor?

Comment: @FREEZE Sim, pode ser outro valor. Mas geralmente não tem motivo pra reciclar a variável, e colocar um valor qualquer também ocupa memória, que é o que se quer evitar. Além disso, `null` tradicionalmente carrega o sentido de ausência de um objeto.

Comment: Hm..., outra pergunta, usando `WeakMap` não dá para ver se um objeto foi removido da memória? `{ let obj = {}; var weak = new WeakMap; weak.set(obj, true); obj = null; }`? Quando executar isso no console e ver o valor de `weak`, provavelmente irá logar a propriedade `obj`. Se esperar minutos também não vai haver diferença. Era para o WeakMap estar vázio.

Comment: @Phanpy Não é bem assim, teste esse seu código. Se tiver dúvidas sobre os weak maps, poste uma pergunta aqui no site sobre isso :)

Comment: Não tenho certeza... *\`Nesse momento, o valor se torna "coletável", mas o GC roda no momento em que a implementação achar mais oportuno.\`* (referência sobre WeakMap)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap]