# Como posso fazer um objeto se 'auto-deletar' em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Tentei algo como:

```
function Objeto(){
  this.del = function(){
    delete this;
  }
}

var a = new Objeto();

a.del();
```

Mas a variável `a` ainda está existindo

---

Eu conheço o método citado na resposta do @bfavaretto, mas para o código em que estou trabalhando não consigo 'subir um nível' na estrutura de variáveis para executar este `delete`, ou `obj = null`;

Eis o trecho em que pretendo utilizar isto:

```
Bullet.prototype.step = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < mobs.length; i++){
        if ((this.x >= mobs[i].x && this.x <= mobs[i].x + mobs[i].size) && (this.y >= mobs[i].y && this.y <= mobs[i].y + mobs[i].size)){
            mobs[i].getHit(this.damage);
            delete this;
        }
    }
};
```

Ou a referência completa:http://codepen.io/GabrielMaia/pen/LEmROB

Comment: Gabriel, o problema é que o `delete` não deleta o objeto e sim uma propriedade de um objeto. Se você testar: `window.teste = new Object(); delete window.teste;`, perde-se a referência para o `teste` mas se alguém tiver uma referência pra ele, é possível acessá-lo.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor por que você está querendo fazer isso?

Comment: É o básico de um sistema de projéteis em um jogo simples...
Quando uma _bullet_ entra em contato com um _mob_ ela deveria sumir, porque quando muitas dessas são carregadas a perda de desempenho é visível... Pretendo fazer com que ao encontrar um _mob_, ou os limites da tela, _bullet_ se destrua, dando lugar a uma nova _bullet_ no array _bullets_

Comment: Então tudo que precisa ser feito é remover essa bala da array. Crie uma função para isso, que receba a bala em questão e remova a posição correspondente da array. Você pode encontrar a posição com `indexOf`, e remover com `splice`.

Comment: It Works \o/
Funcionou perfeitamente com esses métodos, fico muito grato.

Comment: Ok @GabrielMaia, que bom que funcionou! Atualizei minha resposta para concentrar a informação num único lugar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente definir todas as referências ao objeto como `null`:

```
a = null;
```

Mas precisa ser todas mesmo. Por exemplo:

```
var b = a;
a = null;
b = null; // não esqueça!
```

**Pergunta relacionada:** [Como funciona o coletor de lixo do JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32979/como-funciona-o-coletor-de-lixo-do-javascript)

---

Considerando [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52039/como-posso-fazer-um-objeto-se-auto-deletar-em-javascript#comment106069_52039) que diz se tratar de uma array de *bullets*, de onde você precisa retirar uma dessas balas: crie uma função para isso, que receba a bala em questão e remova a posição correspondente da array. Você pode encontrar a posição com [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), e remover com [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Algo assim:

```
var bulletArray = []; // considere populada
function removeBullet(bullet) {
    var index = bulletArray.indexOf(bullet);
    bulletArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```