# Como funciona o Garbage Collector no Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collector

Estava lendo alguns artigos na web e resolvi ver se no SO PT tinha alguma coisa a respeito em JavaScript.

Como sabemos, em linguagens de baixo nível nós mesmos cuidamos do gerenciamento de memória, isso é transparente. Em linguagens de alto nível, esse processo está debaixo dos panos e geralmente desenvolvedores que não aprenderam as linguagens de baixo nível, não sabem como funciona o processo.

Em algumas linguagens o GC pode **congelar o programa** enquanto roda a limpeza e depois resume o programa o que faz com que ele geralmente só rode quando o programa está ocioso. Implementações mais recentes tem uma estratégia melhor, rodam esse processo de forma assíncrona, sem bloquear o programa.

Em resumo eu quero saber como funciona exatamente o processo do GC no JS

- Existe diferença do GC para o JS (Browser) e o JS (NodeJS)?
- De quanto em quanto tempo ele roda?
- Ele possui uma estratégia boa para fazer essa limpeza?
- Podemos facilitar esse processo quando
  for necessário alocar muita memória para um objeto e só vamos precisar de algum elemento dentro dele, e não todo o objeto?

Posso dar um exemplo desse ultimo caso:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const getData = async () => {
   const { data } = await axios.get('https://foo.net/bar')
   //vamos imaginar que essa data é um objeto gigantesco, tudo que eu preciso é o objeto software que está dentro de data
   const mySoftware = data.software
   Object.keys(data).forEach(key => delete data[key])
   //note que depois de recuperar o objeto software, eu quebro todas as referencias de data
   //nesse momento, acredito que o GC já possa limpar esses outros objetos da memória (uma vez que não existem mais nenhuma referência direta e estão soltos na memória), mantendo apenas a referência de 'software'
}
```

> Ainda assim, não posso afirmar com certeza se o GC vai conseguir limpar da memória as referencias além de 'software'. Sei que ele possui uma estratégia de rodar quando a CPU está ociosa, pois o processo do GC pode levar a consumo de processamento

Comment: Isso me parece um tema para um artigo de várias páginas. Só quero resolver um mal entendido aqui: _Em linguagens de alto nível, esse processo está debaixo dos panos_. Essa afirmação está equivocada, uma linguagem de alto nível é uma linguagem de programação voltada para humanos, que abstrai a arquitetura do computador. Linguagens como C ou C++ são de alto nível, e nelas você precisa manusear a memória parcialmente de forma explicita.

Comment: Depende mais da engine do que da linguagem em si. A pergunta me parece _extremamente_ ampla, embora extremamente interessante. O tópico de GCs por si só já é gigante, some ao funcionamento no JavaScript (incluindo as várias engines diferentes) e fica maior ainda. Sugiro que comece por [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) e vá seguindo as referências.

Comment: @Andre, C e C++ podem sim ser consideradas de baixo nível se comparadas com linguagens de _nível maior_ (como JavaScript). A definição é imprecisa e portanto abre espaço para esses relativismos. O trecho em questão da pergunta não me parece equivocado.

Comment: GC não tem muito a ver com linguagem, e sim com a implementação, como comentado pelo @LuizFelipe. Você pode ter 10 browsers ou motores JS, cada um com um GC completamente diferente (ou algum sem GC, por exemplo, que gerencie de outra forma). JavaScript ou o EcmaScript são o que existe na especificação de fato. Se lá não fala em como deve ser o GC, é impossível uma resposta para a pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco Compreendo, então de fato o GC vai depender de onde o Javascript está sendo executado. Concordo com o Luiz também, tentei deixar o menos ampla possível mas ainda sim ficou ampla demais, eu poderia me limitar ao GC do NodeJS, mas ainda não tenho certeza se deixaria menos ampla.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada/possível duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32979/como-funciona-o-coletor-de-lixo-do-javascript. Porém a dúvida lá é algo mais elementar, assim como a minha resposta.